# ¿tengo este error is "used uninitialized in this function "no se como solucionarlo?

Tags: c++

error pruebas.cpp:18:28: warning: 'var' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
18 |   cout<<"[pruebas*]"<n1<<endl;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct pruebas{
   int n1 = 1;
   int n2 = 2;
   int n3 = 3;
   int n4 = 4;
};

int main(){
  struct pruebas *var;
    
  cout<<"[pruebas*]"<<var->n1<<endl;
  cout<<"[pruebas*]"<<var->n2<<endl;
  cout<<"[pruebas*]"<<var->n3<<endl;
  cout<<"[pruebas*]"<<var->n4<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[image: error 1]

Comment: Efectivamente, nunca inicializas `var`, y es un puntero por lo que es peligroso no inicializarlo, pues apuntará a una dirección inválida y al tratar de hacer `var->p1` tendrás un segfault.

Comment: @abulafia como puedo solucionarlo correctamente

Comment: Dale una direccion valida, ya sea que la asignes manualmente (`malloc`, `new`), o usa una variable normal, no un puntero.

Comment: @Pablochaches y como puedo hacer eso , soy nuevo en c++

Comment: @Pablochaches como puedo asignar una variable a estructura ?

Comment: Hay algun motivo por el que lo haces un puntero? La solucion mas simple es que sea una variable normal.

Comment: @Pablochaches si tengo que presentarlo con punteros, es el tema que estoy aprendiendo

Comment: @Pablochaches no entiendo porque no puedo con puntero, pero si con variables

Comment: A donde crees que apunta el puntero? Este no apunta a ninguna direccion valida. Puedes crear una variable normal, y luego que el puntero apunte a esta, o puedes asingar la memoria manualmente usando `new` o `malloc` (Optimamente usarias un puntero inteligente, pero supongo que los veras mas tarde).